# cshtml view page and Script issue in mvc razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

this is the scenario 
i am using MVC 5 in visual studio 2015 
created a view 
and add following inside it

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "test page";
}

<h2>test page</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">        

        function anyfuction() {
            var str =   ' <script type="text/javascript">'
            str += 'function abc() {console.log("why is this happining");'
            str += '}'
            str += '</script>';
        }

</script>
```

you will notice that

```
str += '</script>';
```

wont work

can any one tell me what i am doing this wrong 
or is it Bug

Comment: Use `str += '<\/script>';` or `str += '</s' + 'cript>';`

Comment: Why are you adding script in you cshtml file! Create external JS file, add you code in it and include that JS in cshtml file.